# The true meaning of forgive & forget

Tags: yoga

I want to know what is true meaning for forgive & forget. How can one truly
understand the meaning of this words.

Comment: I don't see how this is a question about Hinduism, so I'm closing your question.

Comment: i don't care :D do what you like :D

Comment: Oh yes I post it here because I see Hinduism as a word for seeking the truth... so if i post this question obout life here Is this not truth seeking?

Comment: Seeking the truth is certainly something that's encouraged in Hinduism, but just because something is encouraged in Hindusm doesn't mean that this site is the appropriate place for it.  Like a math question would be off-topic here, even though it may be seeking the truth.  This site is for questions about Hinduism itself.

Comment: You are right hehe, go and delete if you like.

Comment: Good question. I like your answer very much. Here is another perspective. Who are you forgiving? and who are you forgetting? Seek the answer to this question and that would reveal to you who you really are. (When I say you, I mean we) ALl the best sir

Comment: I'm forgiving, for that, I will never stop giving hahahah :D I will think obout it :D thank you Sai :D

Answer (score 1):

I discover this while I was doing yoga. And I think It's quite true :)

- **FOR** you to **GIVE**, you must to **FORGIVE.**
- **FOR** you to **GET**, you must to **FORGET.**

**FOR | GIVE** & **FOR | GET**, you must to **FORGIVE & FORGET**.